# Two break lines in Markdown

Tags: javascript, markdown

I have the following JS string that creates markdown with a proper breakline between the two lines:

```
`this is some text${'  '}
and this is a new line
`
```

Notice the two explicit spaces at the end of the first line. However, I can't figure out how to do two break lines. I've tried adding 4 spaces, but is not working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you can throw in the line break `<br />`  character to let you skip as many lines as you like.

```
this is some text${'<br /><br />'}
```

this is some text${'
'}

Comment: You should expand on your answer more than just blindly offering a solution. It would help the OP (and future readers) learn to solve rather than to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `` backticks for this: **ES6 template strings**.

```
let text = `this is some text${'  '} \n \n and this is a new line`
```

Comment: I'm already using backticks. The problem is that I dont know how to do two breaklines.

Comment: can you please write, what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a code block or raw HTML (see below). But, first let's address why your attempts do not work...

Markdown is not interpreted inside code blocks and spans. Otherwise, how would you demonstrate Markdown syntax within a Markdown document. Therefore, the double spaces to force a linebreak are ignored within your code span. Additionally, any `<br>` tag is assumed to be part of the code and escaped (as `&lt;br&gt;`) to be displayed in the span.

Code delimited by single backticks is a code span, not a code block. Code spans do not preserve all whitespace. They follow HTML's normal whitespace behavior of collapsing all whitespace to a single space.

If you want to preserve all whitespace, including newlines, then you should place your code in a code block. Within a code block, all newlines are preserved with no need to add extra spaces. There are a few ways to represent a code block. Of course, the standard way of indenting the block:

```
Some document text

    this is some text${'  '}
    and this is a new line

More document text
```

Alternatively, if you are using a Markdown implementation which supports fenced code blocks (not all do), then you can used the triple backtick to delimit your block of code:

````
Some document text

```
this is some text${'  '}
and this is a new line
```

More document text
````

Both of the above render the same:

> Some document text
>
> ```
> this is some text${'  '}
> and this is a new line
> ```
>
> More document text

Notice that the newline is preserved. No special tricks necessary.

All of that said, if you really need a code span which contains a line break, that it outside of the scope of Markdown's syntax. However, as is always the case, anything you can't do in Markdown can be done with raw HTML. Therefore you could do the following:

```
<code>this is some text${'  '}<br>and this is a new line</code>
```

Which renders as:

> `this is some text${'  '}
> and this is a new line`